# click on the Menu bar item to show a window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

Here's my code:

```
if ([window isVisible]) {
   [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
   [window orderOut:nil]; 
   return;
} 
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
return;
```

but if the user clicks/changes the current window and then clicks on menu bar it will close the window. How do I stop that?

Comment: Windows aren't supposed to close until told. You likely have a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing whether the window is ordered in (`isVisible`), test whether it is the active window (`[NSApp mainWindow]` or `[NSApp keyWindow]`—[details](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/ChangingMainKeyWindow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000236-128794)) and whether your application is active (`[NSApp isActive]`).